Facebook Send Dialog URL Redirect kError 1545116 error
I am unable to get the Facebook Send Dialog as a URL to work. No matter what I try out I get the following error, so I assume I am using the Facebook Send Dialog wrong.
An error occurred. Please try later

API Error Code: 1
API Error Description: An unknown error occurred
Error Message: kError 1545116: Thread disabled: This thread is disabled

The documentation says the following:
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?
  app_id=123456789
  &amp;link=http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/15/travel/europe-favorite-streets.html
  &amp;redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/

Can anyone give me a working example of such as a link, or even know what the error means? I have tried many variations of different links. Could there be some settings in the Facebook app that needs to be changed?
I have also tried Send Dialog with the js FB SDK getting the same error there.

You did remove the whitespace from the URL, yes? The redirect URI matches your app's "website" platform setting's domain?
